# Error trying to create roles using rolify gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rolify

How to use rolify gem? I've not been able to run it in the console to try it out. I followed the documentation. Getting this error from paper trail - `ActiveRecord::NotNullViolation (PG::NotNullViolation: ERROR:  null value in column "item_id" violates not-null constraint)`
`DETAIL:  Failing row contains (919, Role, null, create, null, null, 2022-11-25 11:24:25.649806, null, {"id": [null, 1], "name": [null, "admin"], "created_at": [null, ...)..` I searched for it and found that some columns might be expecting UUID but getting an ID. My roles table looks like this -

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table(:roles) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, type: :uuid, polymorphic: true

      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:users_roles, id: false) do |t|
      t.references :user, type: :uuid
      t.references :role
    end

    add_index(:roles, [:name, :resource_type, :resource_id])
    add_index(:users_roles, [:user_id, :role_id])
  end
end
```

I've spent a lot of time trying to debug it to no avail.

I can do `User.first.roles` and `User.first.has_role?(:admin)` but doing `User.first.add_role(:admin)` gives me the above error from the paper trail gem.

I also tried making the roles tables' ID as UUID but it throws me this error -
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedFunction: ERROR:  operator does not exist: uuid = bigint) LINE 1: ... "roles" INNER JOIN "users_roles" ON "roles"."id" = "users_r... ^ HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

My paper trail table looks like this -

```
def change
    create_table :versions do |t|
      t.string   :item_type, null: false
      t.uuid     :item_id,   null: false
      t.string   :event,     null: false
      t.string   :whodunnit
      t.text     :object, limit: TEXT_BYTES
      t.datetime :created_at
    end
    add_index :versions, %i[item_type item_id]
  end
```

I cannot change the `item_id` type to integer because we already have the whole application using it.

I am using rails 6.1 and ruby 2.7.

Comment: If you want to use a uuid for the roles table you need to use  `t.references :role, type: :uuid`  in `users_roles` as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a uuid instead of a bigint for the primary key you need to also set the type for any references to that table:

```
class RolifyCreateRoles < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table(:roles, id: :uuid) do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :resource, type: :uuid, polymorphic: true
      t.timestamps
    end

    create_table(:users_roles, id: false) do |t|
      t.references :user, type: :uuid
      t.references :role, type: :uuid # this was missing
    end

    add_index(:roles, [:name, :resource_type, :resource_id])
    add_index(:users_roles, [:user_id, :role_id])
  end
end
```

Comment: Note that versioning the `roles` table might not be very useful unless you actually intend on letting users create roles on the fly. Typically that's just done by the developers. What you might want to audit is who grants/revokes which role to whom and when but thats unfortunately not really something that Rolify provides. Rolify just uses a "stupid" HABTM relationship and there is no UserRole model that you can track with papertrail.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It really did solve it. I never thought something this small might cause me such trouble. I agree with what you say, but we are using devise for granting/revoking the roles.